# $.post in ajaxstop function looping continously

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to call a `$.post` function after all ajax calls are completed. The call is being triggered just that it runs on a continuous loop.

```
var jQuery_1_11_0 = $.noConflict(true);
jQuery_1_11_0(document).ready(function () {
    var domain = '<?php echo $url; ?>';
   // AJAX 1
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'lib/ajax.html',
        data: {/* some data*/},
        beforeSend: function (data) {/* some code */},
        complete: function () {
            $.getJSON('lib/get-details.html', function(data) {
            // some code here
        }
    });
    // AJAX 2
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'lib/ajax.html',
        data: {/*some code*/},
        beforeSend: function (data) {/*some code*/},
        complete: function () {
            $.getJSON('lib/get-details.html', function(data) {
            // some code here
        }
    });
    // After those 2 calls (they are actually 6, shortened the code)
    // are complete I want to start this one, which starts but run continuously.
    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        $.post('lib/ajax.html?action=update_date',{domain: domain});
    });
});
```

Comment: do you mean including the ajax calls in the complete callback?

Comment: Since you make an ajax request every time an ajax request finished, **of course** it loops!

Comment: @ArunPJohny, No, in the complete are the jsons, and they work properly. Quentin, hmm, and how should I approach it.

Comment: I was thinking that the `ajaxstop` function gets applied only on the ajax calls before it, not also inside the function.

Comment: @user3467855 You can try to flag it as running now. if the flag is on you wont call $.post function and turn flag off on callback of $.post function. so it wont get to run in loop but we should know why you are doing this to be more clear.

Comment: @Azadrum I noticed that ajaxstop is the easiest way to do it. $when and others are a bit more difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will loop as you are calling $.post on ajaxStop event of document. $.post will create an ajax call and when it finishes, it will ajaxStop.
your looping problem can be solved using simple flag variable. flag will restrict to create $.post once only. :)

```
var jQuery_1_11_0 = $.noConflict(true);
jQuery_1_11_0(document).ready(function () {
    var domain = '<?php echo $url; ?>';
   // AJAX 1
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'lib/ajax.html',
        data: {/* some data*/},
        beforeSend: function (data) {/* some code */},
        complete: function () {
            $.getJSON('lib/get-details.html', function(data) {
            // some code here
        }
    });
    // AJAX 2
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'lib/ajax.html',
        data: {/*some code*/},
        beforeSend: function (data) {/*some code*/},
        complete: function () {
            $.getJSON('lib/get-details.html', function(data) {
            // some code here
        }
    });
    // After those 2 calls (they are actually 6, shortened the code)
    // are complete I want to start this one, which starts but run continuously.
    var isDone=false;
    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
        if(isDone)return;
        isDone=true;
        $.post('lib/ajax.html?action=update_date',{domain: domain});
    });
});
```

Comment: It will be working for 1 time / page load. if you start sequence over without refreshing the page. your $.post code will not run this time due to the isDone set true on last sequence.
And it will run for once only for the first ajax request completed on the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If you are waiting for only first and second ajax not the requests in the complete callbacks then use [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

```
var jQuery_1_11_0 = $.noConflict(true);
jQuery_1_11_0(document).ready(function () {
    var domain = '<?php echo $url; ?>';
    // AJAX 1
    var a1 = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'lib/ajax.html',
        data: {}, // some data},
        beforeSend: function (data) {}, // some code},
        complete: function () {
            $.getJSON('lib/get-details.html', function (data) {
                // some code here
            })
        });
    // AJAX 2
    var a2 = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'lib/ajax.html',
        data: {}, //some code},
        beforeSend: function (data) {}, //some code},
        complete: function () {
            $.getJSON('lib/get-details.html', function (data) {
                // some code here
            })
        });
    // After those 2 calls (they are actually 6, shortened the code)
    // are complete I want to start this one, which starts but run continuously.
    $.when(a1, a2).done(function () {
        $.post('lib/ajax.html?action=update_date', {
            domain: domain
        });
    });
});
```